# Mule: Unable to dispatch event with Mule JDBC Connector

Tags: mule

I am trying to save this data to a database using the following jdbcConnector but I get an 
   error that the event could not be dispatched.

```
     <jdbc:connector name="DatabaseConnector" dataSource-ref="datasource" > 
        <jdbc:query key="insertVolumeDetails" value="insert into VolumeSearchInfo 
       ( Id, 
        subCategoryId, 
        subCategoryDetailId, 
        classification, 
        Author,
        ISBN,
        createdDate,
        createdBy,
        updatedDate,
        updatedBy
        )
        VALUES(#[Long.valueOf(xpath('Document/Heading/Id'))],
        #[Long.valueOf(xpath(&quot;Document/Title/SubCategoryId/SubCategoryId[text()`enter code here`='EDFL']/../Manuscript/text()&quot;))],
        #[xpath('Document/Catalog/SubCategory/SubCategoryDetails/SubCategoryDetailId/text()'],
        #[xpath('Document/Catalog/SubCategory/SubCategoryDetails/Topic/classification/text()'],
        #[xpath('Document/Catalog/SubCategory/SubCategoryDetails/Author/text()'],
        #[xpath('Document/Catalog/SubCategory/SubCategoryDetails/ISBN/text()'],
        #[function:now],
        #[server.userName],
        #[function:now],
        #[server.userName])">
        </jdbc:query>  
    </jdbc:connector>
```

Does anyone know what the issue is, Mule does give much information even thought I set the

mule.exception.verbose to true. The connector above does connect to the database, but
   fails to insert the data using the above JDBCConnector.

Comment: Without any stack trace or log it's hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: The error was that the event could not be routed. However, that was to do with one xpath expression that was not terminated properly. The data can now be saved but not with the correct values. None of the values in the XML are resolved correctly.